# Alternative link to download modules from drupal.org

Tags: community-official-site

I am unable to download these modules for Drupal 7. It shows the "Not Found" error.

1. https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr
2. https://www.drupal.org/project/fuzzysearch

Is there an alternative link to download these modules?

Comment: I can able to download those modules using Drush. 
`> drush dl search_api_solr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the version control tab on the module page and it will give you instructions to download it via Git.

To get up and running with Git look at [Installing Git](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/git/install).